# Facebook Page Tab Always show

Tags: facebook, api, tabs, fbml

I have facebook page tab. It only shows as a landing page if the user doesn't "like" us. Is there a way (perhaps with Facebook API) to always show it, regardless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How to set the default landing tab for fans?**

I am afraid this is **NOT** possible.